# Play! 1.2.5 does the render function expose all of the entity fields in html?

Tags: playframework-1.x

I have a question about the render function of the playframework. In my code example is the password exposed if i never use the ${user.password} in html?

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    public String name;
    public String password;
}
```

Controller

```
...
public static void page() {
    List<User> users = User.findAll(); 
    render(users)
}
```

${user.password} is not used.

```
...
#{list items: users, as: 'user'}
<td>${user.name}</td>
#{/list}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't. Don't forget that Play is a server side framework not client side. Meaning that what is not send to the front, is not exposed.

What actually happens when you call `render`, is you call a function server side to generate a html file that will be sent to the client once completed.